# Update DOM after updating variable

Tags: javascript, html

The idea is to update the ID in the API key. I can update the variable but the DOM won't display the changes. IMO is where the vessel's ID is and that is what will display the relevent data.

I've tried with with an AddEventListener but since i'm new to javascript i have no idea what to search for or what to do. Hope someone out there can push me to the right direction.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadScript);

let vesselCall;
let imo;

let url =
  "https://services.marinetraffic.com/api/vesselmasterdata/v:3/API_KEY/imo:" +
  imo +
  "/protocol:jsono";

function changeVessel() {
  let input = document.querySelector("#changeImo").value;
  imo = input;
}

async function loadScript() {
  let vesselApi = await fetch(url);
  vesselCall = await vesselApi.json();
  console.log(vesselCall);

  let vesselTemplate = document.querySelector("#vessel").content;
  let vessel = vesselTemplate.cloneNode(true);

  vessel.querySelector(".name").textContent = vesselCall["DATA"][0]["NAME"];
  vessel.querySelector(".mmsi").textContent = vesselCall["DATA"][0]["MMSI"];
  vessel.querySelector(".imo").textContent = vesselCall["DATA"][0]["IMO"];
  vessel.querySelector(".type").textContent =
    vesselCall["DATA"][0]["VESSEL_TYPE"];
  vessel.querySelector(".built").textContent = vesselCall["DATA"][0]["BUILD"];

  document.querySelector(".vessel").appendChild(vessel);
}
```

THE HTML is just a template and a form that has a onclick to changevessel().

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. So you update the `imo` variable via some button or something, right? Your problem then is to re-fetch the API response with the update `imo`?

Comment: @Nick - That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is to refetch the API response after IMO changes, you should just call `#loadScript` from within `#changeVessel`. As the URL changes when IMO changes, my suggestion is to build the URL in `#changeVessel` and pass it as a parameter to `#loadScript`.

```
function changeVessel () {
    const updatedIMO = document.querySelector("#changeImo").value;
    const url = "https://services.marinetraffic.com/api/vesselmasterdata/v:3/API_KEY/imo:"
        + updatedIMO
        + "/protocol:jsono";
    loadScript(url);
}

async function loadScript (url) {
     // ....
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. But i have one question now how would i prevent it from duplicating? because now it just adds the new API under the old one.

Comment: You could store the last IMO used and call `loadScript` only if the updated value is different from the last one.

Comment: A better suggestion would be to disable or remove the button that triggers `changeVessel` and to enable it again when the content in `#changeImo` changes.

Comment: Wouldn't i need to clear the template everytime before i append the new data?

Comment: It depends on the expected behaviour.

Comment: the expected behavior is to show data about a vessel. So the script just needs to clear the old data and show the new data.

Comment: Have you tried to empty the DOM element `.vessel` before appending `vessel` to it?

Comment: Yeah i just tried   document.querySelector(".vessel").innerHTML = "";
and then cloning the template again with the new data. and worked perfectly! THANK YOU ALOT.